# Understanding the tiling of tensor cores using CUDA on V100

Tags: cuda

I have a toy code heavily borrowing from NVidia's [simpleTensorCoreGEMM.cu](https://github.com/NVIDIA-developer-blog/code-samples/blob/master/posts/tensor-cores/simpleTensorCoreGEMM.cu). I swapped out their random generation of matrices for a function that reads in matrices from files.

Using this toy code and multiplying two matrices of size `[2000 x 10000] * [10000 x 3008]` works beautifully.  The output is as expected.

When I try a much larger multiplication `[20000 x 10000] * [10000 x 30000]`, the output goes horribly wrong and 2/3's of the rows are 0's.

I'm convinced that this is a result of me not understanding the lines of code:

```
// blockDim.x must be a multple of warpSize
// 128x4 means we have 16 warps and a block computes a 64x64 output tile
blockDim.x = 128;
blockDim.y = 4;

gridDim.x = (MATRIX_M + (WMMA_M * blockDim.x / 32 - 1)) / (WMMA_M * blockDim.x / 32);
gridDim.y = (MATRIX_N + WMMA_N * blockDim.y - 1) / (WMMA_N * blockDim.y);
```

Even if it is not the source of my error, I should still understand what it is doing.  I understand setting `blockDim.*` There are 32 threads per warp, 128*4/32 = 16 warps.

QUESTION : Could someone explain to me the logic behind the values of  and the computation of `gridDim.x` and `gridDim.y`?  The correct usage of the tensor cores seems to be very sensitive to using the correct values for `gridDim.*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple introductory points:

1. For understanding, this code is intended to accompany [this blog article](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/programming-tensor-cores-cuda-9/).  The last part of that blog, the section  "Programmatic Access to Tensor Cores in CUDA 9.0" is definitely useful for understanding this code.
2. As mentioned in the [readme for that code](https://github.com/NVIDIA-developer-blog/code-samples/blob/master/posts/tensor-cores/README.md) an easier method to access the performance of tensor cores (especially for the basic matrix multiply operations you seem to be playing with) is simply to use a CUBLAS function, such as [cublasGemmEx](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-GemmEx) which will make intelligent use of tensor cores under the right circumstances.

Now to your question:

> Could someone explain to me the logic behind the values of and the computation of `gridDim.x` and `gridDim.y`?

These values are sizing the CUDA grid to be sufficient for the size of the matrix multiply problem requested.  We need to approach this hierarchically.

- First of all, the tensor core capability is accessed at the warp level.  The blog article indicates that "The strategy we’ll employ is to have a single warp responsible for a single 16×16 section of the output matrix"  Therefore the output matrix dimensions will drive the dimensions of the CUDA grid used to compute the result. ([Typical naive realizations of matrix multiply](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory) also determine grid size based on output matrix size.  More specifically they assign one thread per output point.  Here we are assigning one 32-thread-warp to be responsible for one 16x16 tile of the output matrix.)  The code uses `WMMA_M` (i.e. how many rows) and `WMMA_N` (i.e. how many columns) to define what a single warp-level tensor core operation will handle.  These values are 16, and this drives the choice of using a 16x16 tile in the output, per warp.
- As is often the case in CUDA, block dimensions can be somewhat arbitrary, but they do frequently affect the grid size (variables).  Warps exist at the block level and the number of warps in a block effectively determine how many 16x16 tiles in the output matrix will be handled per block.   In this particular case, the code is choosing block dimensions of 128 (`blockDim.x`) by 4 (`blockDim.y`).  This happens to be 4 warps "wide" by 4 warps "high", so each block is handling a 4x4 set of tiles in the output, which means each block is responsible for 64x64 output points.  Note that these `blockDim` and `gridDim` variables in host code are logically separate from (although end up being the same numerically as) the `blockDim` and `gridDim` built-in variables in CUDA device code.
- Given the above, the m,n, and k parameters of a typical BLAS GEMM operation have the same meaning here.  m is the number of rows of the left hand side input matrix.  n is the number of columns of the right hand side input matrix.  k is the number of columns of the left matrix, which must match the number of rows of the right matrix.  Therefore m,n define the dimensions of the output matrix.  These are indicated in the code as `MATRIX_M` and `MATRIX_N` respectively.

With the above groundwork laid, we can then state the arithmetic needed to compute `gridDim.x` and `gridDim.y` in host code.

1. We must choose enough threads in the x dimension, so that when divided by 32 (the width of a warp in the x dimension) and then multiplied by `WMMA_M` (the output tile width responsibility of that warp), we have enough threads to cover the width of the output matrix.
2. We must choose enough threads in the y dimension, so that when divided by 1 (the "height" of a warp in the y dimension) and then multiplied by `WMMA_N` (the output tile height responsibility of that warp), we have enough threads to cover the height of the output matrix.  Note that the "height" of the warp in the y dimension is definitely 1 in this case, because the code requires that the the block width dimension be a whole number multiple of the warp size.  Therefore any warp has a constant `threadIdx.y` component, across the warp.
3. To go from threads determined in 1 and 2 above, to blocks in each dimension, we must scale (divide) each by the corresponding threadblock dimension.  Therefore the grid thread dimension in x must be divided by `blockDim.x` (in host code), scaled as in 1 above, to get the total grid dimension (number of blocks) in x.  This division operation is the usual CUDA "round up" integer divide operation, to scale the number of blocks to be equal to or larger than the threads needed, to account for matrix sizes that are not evenly divisibly by the block size.

Putting all that together, we have:

```
gridDim.x = (MATRIX_M + (WMMA_M * blockDim.x / 32 - 1)) / (WMMA_M * blockDim.x / 32);
   ^            ^             ^                                   ^
   |            |             |                    divided by the block size scaled for the
   |            |             |                     portion of the output matrix it covers.
   |            |           rounded up
   |         the matrix size
  The grid in blocks is
```

And similarly for the y grid dimension.  The only real difference is that 32 threads in x (a warp-width) is responsible for a 16x16 output tile whereas on a single thread in y (a warp "height") is responsible for that 16x16 output tile.

Comment: So this should work for any matrix multiplication where the matrix dimensions are divisible by 16?

Comment: If you work through the above math for the coverage of a single threadblock, using the actual values in the code, you will find that each threadblock covers a 64x64 patch of the output.  Therefore I think the code probably works for any `MATRIX_M` and `MATRIX_N` that are evenly divisible by 64.  Beyond that, I haven't studied the code to see if it will handle a finer grain than that.  The purpose of the code there is not as a black-box library routine that just works for everything, but as a learning vehicle.  If you want a black-box library routine that just works, I suggest using CUBLAS.

Comment: I tried `MATRIX_M` = 20032, `MATRIX_N`  = 30016, and `MATRIX_K`  = 10048 with that code and it seemed to work correctly.  The code itself claims that these values need only to be divisible by 16.  So I tried your values of `MATRIX_M` = 20000, `MATRIX_N` = 30000, and `MATRIX_K` = 10000 and the code reported that it worked correctly also.  So it may be that the code works just fine if the dimensions are divisible by 16 (that is what the code claims).  I'm not sure what the problem is in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  The problem with my code was a bug where I was passing the wrong dimension for `MATRIX_N` in `wmma_example <<< gridDim, blockDim >>> (a_fp16, b_fp16, c_wmma, MATRIX_M, MATRIX_N, MATRIX_K, alpha, beta)`. This explanation definitely helped my understanding here.